# Removing attributes from elements when they have a certain value

Tags: xslt, xsd, xslt-2.0

I'm writing a stylesheet to "canonicalize" XML schemas, in order to make comparing them easier.  It will sort top-level elements by name, order attribute in a fixed order etc.  This is what I have for attributes so far:

```
<xsl:template match="xsd:attribute">
    <xsl:copy>      
        <xsl:copy-of select="@name"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@type"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@ref"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@use"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@default"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*">
            <xsl:sort select="name()"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Now I would like to also remove redundant attributes.  For example, `use = "optional"` should be dropped, since `optional` is the default anyway.

So my question is: what would be the easiest way to enhance the code above in order to drop the `use` attribute when its value is `optional`?

Comment: Attributes are not ordered in the XSLT/XPath/XQuery data model. Also what do you want to achieve with that code using both various `copy-of` for some attributes and then applying templates to all attributes, which order is that supposed to create?

Comment: I do suggest using `apply-templates` instead of `copy-of` to transform attributes, as `copy-of` will fail when the designated attribute is not in fact present on the context node.  Per-attribute templates could also then give you appropriate leverage for omitting attributes that take their default values -- they can just transform to nothing in that case.

Comment: It orders the specified attributes in the listed order (so first `name` then `type` then `ref`, etc.).  Any other attributes not specifically named will come at the end, sorted by name (that's what the `apply-templates select="@*"` does).

Comment: No, @pegasus.  First, attribute order is *insignificant* in the relevant data model.  If you happen to reliably get the attributes out in the lexical order in which the `copy-of` elements appear then that's a characteristic of your particular XSLT processor, not a guarantee provided by the XSLT language.  Second, the `apply-templates` will transform *all* the attributes, not just the ones that have not already been the subject of `copy-of` elements.

Comment: But your `apply-templates` processes all attributes including those you did already try to output and that way the last step with apply-templates due to point 9 in https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#constructing-complex-content wins

Comment: @JohnBollinger it's working fine like this, using `copy-of`, even when some of the named attributes are not present.  Tested with Saxon9-HE in XSLT 2.0 mode.  Using apply-templates might be the way forward but I couldn't come up with a working solution.  My knowledge of XSLT is very limited.  I did put at least an hour into it though - googling for solutions, reading documentation, etc.

Comment: @JohnBollinger & @Martin Honnen: thanks for pointing that out,  I think you're right on both counts, it only works because Saxon happens to maintain the order of the attributes when serializing.  I will need to add a filter on the `@*` condition.  Something like this `@*[name(.) != 'name' && name(.) != 'type'...]` seems to do the trick, though there are probably more elegant ways to go about it.

Comment: How about you instead just remove all the `copy-of` elements?  They aren't doing anything useful for you anyway, and that will facilitate using attribute-specific templates to accomplish your aim of omitting attributes that take their default values (relative to leaving in the `copy-of` and filtering out those particular attributes from the `apply-templates`).

Comment: They do allow me to order them, which is essential for me, even if it just happens to work and it's not in any way guaranteed by the standard.  I figured a working solution for now, will post it in a minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@JohnBollinger and @MartinHonnen correctly pointed out that the `@*` condition will insert all the attributes, even the ones selected above.  So the condition has to be refined.  It was also pointed out that according to the specification the order of attributes cannot be ensured.  The fact that they *are* being ordered is simply an artifact of how my processor (Saxon9-HE) happens to work.  I'm fine with this though.  Here is the solution I arrived at:

```
<xsl:template match="xsd:attribute">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@name" />
        <xsl:copy-of select="@type" />
        <xsl:copy-of select="@ref" />
        <xsl:copy-of select="@use[string() != 'optional']" />
        <xsl:copy-of select="@default" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[name(.) != 'use']">
            <xsl:sort select="name()" />
        </xsl:apply-templates>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

I didn't add the other attribute names to the negative filter on `@*` since Saxon won't duplicate attributes and leaves them in the required order even if it's re-inserted by the `@*` clause.  So this does fulfill my present needs with the least effort, even though it's not a generic solution (which I don't actually need).

Comment: `select="@*[name(.) != 'use']"` can be written elegantly as `select="@* except @use"` in XSLT/XPath 2 and later.